# Elastic Beans + Django. Switch HTTP to HTTPS using Load Balancer

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

Dear Stackoverflow community. This question has been asked before, but my question is little bit different.
So I am using Elasticbeanstalk to deploy my Django Backend and RDS for database (PostgreSQL).
EB generated a link for my backend --> http://XXXXX.region.elasticbeans.com. The issue is that when I send a request from the frontend side (HTTPS), it gives a "Blocked loading mixed active content" error, which comes from HTTPS to HTTP request. As far as I am concerned I have to change configuration of the Load Balancer of my EC2 instance and add redirection. In order to successfully do that I am required to have a SSL certificate. However, when I use ACM (Certificate Manager) in order to generate one using the exact same link for the backend, it automatically rejects my request.
So my question is that what is the exact process of obtaining the SSL cert. for the default EB link, or maybe there are easier ways to redirect HTTP to HTTPS from the AWS console?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is that what is the exact process of obtaining the SSL cert. for the default EB link,

There is no process as this is not possible. You need to have **your own domain** (e.g. myapp.com). Only then you can setup SSL using ACM. Once you have your own domain, the full process of setting up https on EB is in [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-ssl-certificate/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved this issue by simply purchasing a cheap domain and everything worked as it should.